# Axios vs Fetch in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I am curious about why people use axios instead of the fetch api in react to make API requests. Is there any advantage to Axios over Fetch or is it just a personal choice ?

Looking to gain some diverse opinions on this.

Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Axios** has extensive browser support; even the old browser *IE11* can run smoothly. `Fetch()`, on the other hand, only confirms *Chrome 42+*, *Firefox 39+*, *Edge 14+*, and *Safari 10.1+*

**Axios** gives an easy-to-use API in a compact package for most of your HTTP connection needs. However, if you prefer to stick with native APIs, nothing stops you from achieving **Axios** features.

However, it's entirely possible to reproduce the Axios library's key features using the `fetch()` method provided by web browsers. Finally, whether it's worth loading a client `HTTP API` depends on whether you're comfortable working with built-in APIs.

[Browser Support for `fetch()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=Fetch)

[Further Reading](https://blog.logrocket.com/axios-or-fetch-api/#:%7E:text=To%20send%20data%2C%20fetch(),set%20in%20the%20options%20object)

Comment: You forgot to mention that axios automaticallynconverts to and from JSON

Comment: @k-wasilewski Absolutely

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed explanation. Really appreciate it.